# How to use GoF design pattern for software robustness?

Tags: java, design-patterns, software-design, software-quality, robustness

Robustness is defined by IEEE as "The degree to which a system or component can function correctly in the presence of invalid inputs or stressful environmental conditions".

What real-world scenarios can illustrate this problem? And what GoF design patterns are suitable for solving robustness?

Since the areas of robustness are error handling, fault tolerance, and recoveryability. But I don't have an idea how to use design patterns to solve it.

```
class Dao {
   ... 
   public void timeout() {
       // some logic here 
       throw new RunTimeException("This session is timeout");
   }
}
```

Many exceptions may be defined in the Dao class.

If I use design patterns to solve this problem, should I create a factory pattern to handle each exception and create a class for each exception?

Comment: Why do you think any GoF design patterns are suitable for solving robustness?

Comment: Design patterns are just another tool, although that is certainly not the way they were presented, which was as a sovereign remedy for all ailments. They weren’t. Like all programming novelties, they were considerably oversold. There was a sustained attempt at the time to force the whole of computer science into design patterns. It failed. Don’t think you have to join that effort at this late date.

Comment: @user207421, pick any year in the history of software engineering and replace "design patterns" with another tool or idea that was oversold as a sovereign remedy for all ailments: formal methods, UML, visual programming, OOP, Agile, ReST, Micro-services, The Cloud™, and the biggest hype du jour: AI. I enjoy rereading your comment in the present and future tense with AI in place of design patterns.

Comment: @jaco0646 I only researched this particular attribute because "robustness" does not appear in ISO/IEC 25010, making it difficult for me to figure this thing out.

Answer (score 3):

GoF and design patterns are just a set of solutions that software engineer noticed keep reoccurring.

Many beginners unfortunately try and cram these design patterns into every problem they see, this is a very bad usage of them.

> Since the areas of robustness are error handling, fault tolerance, and recoveryability. But I don't have an idea how to use design patterns to solve it.

GoF does not guarantee robustness (or anything really). GoF is just a bunch of really common solutions that four engineers have noticed. Other design patterns (non GoF) too, are just common solutions (but not as widely recognized as GoF's)

Comment: Agree entirely. Most of them aren’t even useful.

Comment: Agreed. It's so common to see design patterns considered as solutions looking for problems that rarely require a design pattern as the solution.

Answer (score 2):

The patterns are not useless, but applying them just for the sake of applying them will overengineer every project.

Knowledge about design patterns allows to better distribute code over classes and interfaces such that it is flexible to use and maintainable.

Robustness means an application can deal with strange input, or with varying conditions such as a partner system that has gone offline. Design patterns do not change the robustness per se.

But if you have well designed code, it is easier to spot the location where error handling needs to be improved. And this indirectly contributes to to more than just robustness.